# Density of a transformation of Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

If we have $X_t$ as a Brownian motion with variance $\sigma^{2}t$ and $X_0 = x$ how can I find the density, $p_{t}(x,y)$ of $Y_t = X_t + t\mu$ with $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$?

I know the expectation of $Y_t = x + t\mu$ and that for $X_t$ (with mean zero and variance $t$) $p_{t}(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{2t}}$

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple actually. Just observe that $t\mu$ is deterministic, so you're simply increasing the mean of your Gaussian by $t\mu$.

Comment: I've been told that the answer I'm supposed to get involves absolute values in the $e$ exponent, so I figured it was something beyond just shifting the mean

Comment: $P[Y_t\leq y] = P[X_t\leq y-\mu t]$ differentiate the above in $y$ and you'll get your density.

Comment: But in this case, what actually is $X_t$? I know its starting point and variance, but how does that translate into something I can integrate

Comment: I don't quite understand what's confusing you I'm afraid! Fix a $t>0$, then $X_t$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-valued Gaussian random variable with mean $x$ and variance $\sigma^2 t$. Denote the density of $X$ by $f_X$, then $f_X(y) = (2\pi \sigma^2t)^{-1/2}\exp(-(x-y)^2/(2\sigma^2t))$. $Y_t$ is given simply by $Y_t= X_t+\mu t$ denoting its density by $f_Y$, we have $f_Y(y) = (2\pi \sigma^2t)^{-1/2}\exp(-(x+\mu t-y)^2/(2\sigma^2t))$.